# Can this positive / negative check be simplified?

Tags: javascript

I basically want to check if newValue goes past targetValue. But targetValue could be either a positive or negative number, so if `( newValue < targetValue )` won't necessarily work.

I coded it the way below, and I may be overthinking things here but I wondered if there's a way to rewrite the if-check a bit more elegantly…

```
var newValue = 0;

function ChangeValue ( targetValue : int )
{
    var isTargetPositive = ( targetValue > 0 );

    if ( isTargetPositive && newValue < targetValue || !isTargetPositive && newValue > targetValue )
        newValue = math.moveTowards( newValue, targetValue, 1 );
    else
        // Do something else
}
```

Comment: You're initializing "newValue" to zero, so if the "targetValue" is greater than zero, "newValue" will **always** be less than "targetValue".

Comment: `newValue < Math.abs(targetValue)`? What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: That code doesn't work anyways.

Comment: That’s a syntax error: `function ChangeValue ( targetValue : int )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that keeps your conditions exactly as they are is removing the `isTargetPositive` variable and replacing your if statement with the following:

```
if ( targetValue > 0 ? newValue < targetValue : newValue > targetValue )
```

Comment: Thanks. That is a bit simpler.

Answer (score 2):

this is almost the same case as in my [chess project](https://github.com/ajax333221/Isepic-Chess) where I changed:

```
if((obj.ActiveColor&&current_val>0) || (!obj.ActiveColor&&current_val<0)){}
```

with

```
var impossible_to_name = (current_val * (obj.ActiveColor?1:-1));

if(impossible_to_name>0){}
```

I know you don't need to cache the var, but in my case I was going to use it later so I cached it, my code is so complex that I couldn't even give a proper name to my var, I am also not entirely sure if this will help you, if I couldn't translate it into your code, chances are you can't neither but I will try to understand my code again and make an edit to my answer.

**Note:** my code was wrapped in `if(current_val){...}` so the value is anything except `0`

Answer (score 1):

```
var newValue = 0;
    function ChangeValue ( targetValue )
    {
        if ( 
    ((targetValue > 0) && (newValue < targetValue)) 
    || 
    ((targetValue < 0) && (newValue > targetValue ))
           )
        {
            newValue = math.moveTowards( newValue, targetValue, 1 );
        }    
        else{
            // Do something else
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always make a subfunction if this is not clear enough

```
function abs_compare(target, number) {
    return target != 0 && ((target > 0 && target > number) || target < number);
}

if (abs_higher(targetValue, newValue)) {
    newValue = math.moveTowards(newValue, targetValue, 1);
}
```

I would also prefer `target != 0` rather than double checking if it is superior or inferior to 0 because it is more clear in your condition statement that it is a forbidden value.

Also, Pointy said that since you have initialized newValue to 0, it will always remains to 0 which is currently false since ChangeValue is a function. The newValue can be changed before the function call.

**UPDATE**

I may have read too fast. Comparing target to 0 won't keep your actual logic and it is the same as the double check. Anyway, you can still use a function.

Also the best answer would rather be using the condition `target > 0 ? target > number : target < number`

Answer (score -1):

Test (input: 5)
isTargetPositive - matched
newValue < targetValue - matched

Test (input: -1)
!isTargetPositive - matched
newValue > targetValue - matched

+ve or -ve integer, it will match the IF.

isTargetPositive && newValue < targetValue, same right? Why use &&?
I think one condition is enough.